# External Object for Android with callback Event

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I'm building an External Object for Android.
I have an asynchronous method and I guess I must to use an Event into the External Object to receive it's callback in Genexus.

But, can anyone show me how to trigger this event in GX from the android java class?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow :) Please familiarize yourself with how to ask a good question :) Please provide us a code you already tried and show us exactly where you failed.

Answer (score 0):

This method:

`mCoordinator.runAction("yourEvent", null);`

And the mCoordinator you can get it at the constructor:

`public YourUC(Context context, Coordinator coordinator, LayoutItemDefinition definition){
}`