# External Object for Android with callback Event send values

Tags: android, mobile, user-controls, genexus

Refer to: [External Object for Android with callback Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133026/external-object-for-android-with-callback-event)

How can i send parameters and received in GX ?

> Class.java

`mCoordinator.setValue('parametro1', 'valor1'); //Is this possible?
    mCoordinator.setValue('parametro2', 'valor2'); 
    mCoordinator.runAction("myEvent", null);`

> GX

`Event UC.myevent
Composite
parametro1 = &sdt.parametro1
EndComposite
EndEvent`

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question , with a better example of what are you trying to achive, tks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to send parameters to the Action Event. You send them in a context Entity.

Depend on what your context is, but for example, you need to get the entity, set your values and send to the event in the context, like:

```
Entity contextEntity = myActivity.getMainFragment().getContextEntity();
contextEntity.setProperty(name, value);
mCoordinator.runAction("myEvent", null);
```

or send explicity in the paramters with:

```
Entity contextEntity = myActivity.getMainFragment().getContextEntity();
contextEntity.setProperty(name, value);
myActivity.getController().runAction(myActivity.getUIContext(), actionDefinition, contextEntity);
```